# Unknown Process in TaskManager and cannot be removed

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, task-manager, tasks

I have just found an unknown process in Task Manager. I have scanned my system with Windows Defender on Windows 8.1 and it could not detect any issues.

But there is something there that shouldn't be there.

I cannot get rid of this process. I can not view its Properties or its file location like I can with any other process because those options are greyed-out/disabled.

How can I find more information about this on my system and how can I get rid of it when Task Manager won't let me perform any operations on it?

[image]

Comment: Download Autoruns and see what it has to say about this mysterious program.

Comment: `Program`... Seems legit... :)

Comment: @kobaltz - lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) To get more info about the process. Process explorer will even give you the information such as where it is located on your computer. If you decide you don't need it or want it then you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) application.

You will find the dead program entry in the LOGON tab, one of the yellow lines. Just uncheck the corresponding line and the program will be removed from the startup items.

The common issue is "File not found" and his line is yellow in the Sysinternals Autorun/Logon tab.
[image]